# Are $L^\infty$ bounded functions closed in $L^2$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, functions, lp-spaces

Is the set $\{ m \in L^2(0,1) : |m|_{L^\infty}\leq A \}$, (i.e. the set of $L^2$ functions with bounded $L^\infty$ norm) a closed subset of $L^2$?

(Closed in the topology induced by the $L^2$-norm)

Comment: well $L^\infty(0,1)$ contains continuous functions with compact support and those are dense in $L^2$(slightly cheating)

Comment: @BigM That's not really relevant, because if $f_n$ is in $L^\infty$ and converges in $L^2$ to $f$ which is not in $L^\infty$, then $f_n$ was not $L^\infty$-bounded. And $L^\infty$ boundedness is the hypothesis here. You are correct that $L^\infty$ itself is not closed in $L^2$, however.

Comment: totally misread the question.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

Call your set $M$. If $\{ f_n \}_{n=1}^\infty \subset M$ and $f_n \to f$ in the sense of $L^2$, then there is a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ which converges almost everywhere to a function $f$. (This is a nontrivial fact, and follows by the "rapidly Cauchy subsequence" argument. The Lebesgue case comes up on page 146 of Royden and Fitzpatrick; the general case comes up on page 397. I presume one could find it in any proof that $L^p$ is complete.) Take $N=\{ x : \exists k \: |f_{n_k}(x)| > A \text{ or } f_{n_k}(x) \not \to f(x) \}$. Then $N$ has measure zero. Off $N$ we get $|f(x)| \leq A$ by preservation of inequalities for real numbers, so $f \in M$.

This is not specific to $L^2$ with $L^\infty$. Provided the space has finite measure, exactly the same argument goes through to show that $L^\infty$-closed balls are closed in $L^p$ for $1 \leq p<\infty$. A similar argument goes through for $L^p$ and $L^r$ whenever $r>p$ and $X$ has finite measure. In the Lebesgue case and a number of related cases, $L^r$ balls are hollow in $L^p$, which means that $L^r$ is a first category subset of $L^p$ in these cases.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I would like to add a question. It seems to me that the aforementioned set of $L^\infty(0,1)$ bounded functions of $L^2(0,1)$ is $L^\infty(0,1)$ itself, since $L^\infty(0,1) \subset L^2(0,1)$.
Therefore, since $\left(L^2(0,1),\langle .,. \rangle_{L^2(0,1)}\right)$ is an Hilbert space and a closed subspace of an Hilbert space is itself Hilbert, could we say that the space of $L^\infty(0,1)$ bounded functions of $L^2(0,1)$ with the $L^2$ scalar product is an Hilbert space ?

Comment: @NiccolòAjroldi The context is not the same. This question is asking whether a ball in $L^\infty([0,1])$ centered at $0$ is closed in $L^2([0,1])$. Your question is about whether $L^\infty([0,1])$ itself is closed in $L^2([0,1])$. This is not immediate from the result about balls because it requires an infinite union of balls to fill out $L^\infty$ and an infinite union of closed sets is not necessarily closed. Your claim actually does not hold. A counterexample is given by $f_n(x)=x^{-p} \chi_{[1/n,1]}$ where $0<p<1/2$, which converges in $L^2$ to $x^{-p}$ which is not $L^\infty$.

Comment: Wow, you are absolutely right, I was missing the ball argument. Thank you for the counterexample!

Comment: Another last question. Is my claim invalid also for $L^\infty([0,1]\times[0,1])$?

Comment: @NiccolòAjroldi The situation is the same in any finite measure space with no atoms.

Comment: Thank you again! I really appreciate it